# Is there already a YAML library/parser for MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, yaml

I want to use YAML to communicate some data across multiple languages.  (Think of it as "language-independent serialization".)  One of these languages is MATLAB, but I can't seem to find a YAML library for that language.  I've checked for "matlab yaml" and "matlab yaml parse" on Google and there don't seem to be any relevant results.  A search of "yaml" on MATLAB Central also left me empty-handed.

Is there really no existing YAML library for MATLAB?  I'm fine with writing one, but I would like to avoid duplicating work.  (Perhaps something to share?)

Comment: Why do you want to use YAML? XML has much better cross-language support.

Comment: What did you end up using and how did it work? I'm in a similar situation and would be interested in hearing.

Comment: Some other high priority things have come up, so I haven't had a chance to try this out yet.  If you try something before I do (I'll post), I'd like to hear about how it goes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I extended [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4134271/1714410)'s code to support more data types as well as writing out of a matlab struct to yaml file. It is not just one m-file therefore I located the sources on http://code.google.com/p/yamlmatlab/
Jiri

Comment: I want to use read YAML on cluster (-nojvm). So, java dependency is not an option. Is there a MEX version around??

Answer (score 3):

Call existing Java YAML import libraries from Matlab. This should be pretty strightforward. Java-Matlab interoperability is pretty good, see matlab help.

Comment: That's a great idea -- didn't even think of it.  Will the data types in Java be coverted into the appropriate types in Matlab?  Never messed with the Java stuff much...

Comment: Numeric types are converted implicitly, strings have to be converted explicitly with either cell(myJavaArray) for arrays or char(myJavaString), see Matlab help, it is pretty good on this topic.

Comment: @AndyL, there is now a matlab wrapper for snakeyaml.

Comment: @AndyL, see jirka's answer on this page

Answer (score 3):

I believe, that the following example can save some time.

First you need to load a YAML document using snake YAML:

```
javaaddpath C:\temp\snakeyaml-1.7.jar
import('org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml')

yamlreader = Yaml();
yml = fileread('C:\temp\test.yml');
jymlobj = yamlreader.load(yml);
```

and afterwards you will need to access data from the java object, I did it using the following routine (note that this is not a general routine and it was developed for a particular type of YAML files, where for example matrices are defined as in Matlab)

```
function Data = Hash2Struct(hashMap)

  Data = [];

  iterator = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext())
     field = iterator.next();
     if ~isempty(field)
        d =  hashMap.get(field);
        switch class(d)
            case {'java.util.LinkedHashMap'}
                Data.(field) = Hash2Struct(d);
            case {'java.util.ArrayList'}
               Data.(field) = str2num(d.toString);               
            otherwise    
                Data.(field) = d;
        end
     end
  end
```

Good luck,
Jan

Comment: I had to modify Jan's code to wrap the key in a java.lang.String() before the hashMap would return the value associated with the key. The result of the .get(field) method, for me would always return nothing.

So you might try changing the line: d = hashMap.get(field) to d = hashMap.get( java.lang.String(field) ), if you have a similar problem. That assumes that your keySet is of type String, of course.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a matlab wrapper for snakeyaml:

http://code.google.com/p/yamlmatlab/

I've tried it out and it works pretty well on a simple yaml file.  There are bugs if the yaml field names are not valid fieldnames and when strings are empty.  I've suggested workarounds for both of these in the issues section on the google code site

Comment: my bad, missed jirka's answer

Answer (score 1):

@AndyL
For sankeyaml, add it to your javapath, then import('org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml'), and it works like the docs; the resulting LinkedHashMap is accessed more or less like a matlab struct.

Comment: You meant classpath by javapath?

Answer (score 0):

There is also MEX implementation by Geoffr Adams called [mat-yaml](https://github.com/biogeo/mat-yaml) with C binding for [libyaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML) parser-emitter).

But it can not be compiled on Windows yet.

Answer (score 0):

[ZozaniDB Database Toolbox](http://zozani.com/zozanidb/) includes a Matlab-native implementation for YAML (distributed as p-files).

```
>> s=yaml_dump(struct('name','apple','calories',53))

  s =

name: apple
calories: 53

>> yaml_parse(s)

ans = 
        name: 'apple'
    calories: 53
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a wrapper for SnakeYAML:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/106765-yaml

```
>> data.a = 1.23;
>> data.b = "hello";
>> data.c = {2, {true, 'world'}, yaml.Null};

>> s = yaml.dump(data)

    "a: 1.23
     b: hello
     c:
     - 2.0
     - [true, world]
     - null
     "
   
>> result = yaml.load(s)

  struct with fields:

    a: 1.2300
    b: "hello"
    c: {[2]  {1×2 cell}  [1×1 yaml.Null]}
```