# convert .mat to csv file results in error: matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to convert a .mat file to csv so that it can be converted to yaml. I am following this question: 
`http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195151-how-to-convert-a-mat-file-into-a-csv-file`

But after writing those commands matlab is giving this error:

```
??? Reference to non-existent field 'M'.
```

These are the commands I entered:

```
>> FileData = load ('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\model3Ddlib.mat');
>> csvwrite ('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\model3Ddlib.csv', FileData.M);
```

Why is this error coming up and what should I do to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

`FileData` is an struct with the stored .mat variables as fields.

Your .mat doesn't contain an `M` variable...

After loading the .mat write  `FileData.` and let autocomplete show you the available fields, or execute `fieldnames(FileData)`

then export to CSV as:

```
csvwrite ('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\model3Ddlib.csv', FileData.<your_field_here>);
```

Comment: autocomplete isn't showing anything and fieldnames() isn't either.

Comment: run `clear all; load ('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\model3Ddlib.mat'); ` check your workspace, if it's empty then so is the .mat

Comment: On running clean all; it says : undefined function or method 'clean' for input args of type 'char'

Comment: The workspace has a 1*1 struct which has 8 fields. But when I try to use these fields it returns error

Comment: It's an struct array. Try `<structname>(1).<fieldname>`

Comment: OK that's working . so do I have to create a separate CSV for each field? And how will I create a single yaml for all those CSVs?

Comment: Yes, you need to do it yourself. for a yaml you'll need low level I/O or check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638018/is-there-already-a-yaml-library-parser-for-matlab (never used it)